# About the word "casual"

Tags: meaning, adjectives, ambiguity

According to what I knew and I have found on the web, in general the word *casual* is the opposite of *everyday*. But in the special case when it refers to clothing, it has a similar meaning to "everyday clothing". And it definitely does not mean "special" or "formal".

This seems illogical to me. Could you please clarify? Is that really the case?

This is especially confusing to me, because in my native language (Hungarian), the literal translation of *casual* is the same word that is used to refer to formal clothing for special events. This seems to make more sense.

Comment: " *casual* is the opposite of *everyday* " -- source?

Comment: What are the definitions of *casual* you found in the dictionaries?

Comment: [Casual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casual)
In the European tradition, casual is the dress code that emphasizes comfort and personal expression over presentation and uniformity. It includes a very wide variety of costume, so it is perhaps better defined by what it is **not** than what it is. The following are **not** considered casual wear:
Ceremonial dress such as royal robes and full dress military costume
Formal wear such as white tie and black tie
Business professional wear such as suits and ties.
Blue jeans and a T-shirt have been described as the "casual uniform".

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Acasual

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/casual says "Occurring at irregular or infrequent intervals; occasional"

Comment: @mplungjan: I read wikipedia too

Comment: This question turns on OP's misunderstanding that because *casual = occasional, not occurring at regular intervals* this somehow conflicts with *everyday = commonplace, not "special"*.

Answer (score 3):

*Casual* is a word which has drifted in meaning, as shown in the entry in [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=casual&searchmode=none):

> **casual (adj.)**
>
> late 14c., "subject to or produced by chance," from Middle French *casuel* (15c.), from Late Latin *casualis* "by chance," from Latin *casus* "chance, occasion, opportunity; accident, event" (see case (n.1)).
>
> Of persons, in the sense of "not to be depended on, unmethodical," it is attested from 1883; meaning "showing lack of interest" is from 1916. Of clothes, "informal," from 1939. Related: *Casually.*

*Casual labour* is work which occurs occasionally, not on a regular basis. It's work which cannot be depended on to happen.

A *casual attitude* indicates that a person is not to be depended on, either because they are unmethodical or uninterested or lazy. *Casual dress* is for when you don't want to make the effort to be formal.

It's interesting to see how the word has extended its meaning from "occasional, by chance" all the way to "everyday, informal".

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there is no tick (I probably deleted cookies, since asking the question), with which I could technically accept your answer. But actually I do accept it.

Comment: We can only merge registered accounts, so I'm of no help, either.

Comment: I suppose it owes much to the very existence of casual clothes themselves; from something the well-off would wear on occasions of particularly informal leisure, to being more frequent, and then extended to the clothes worn by the less well-off (partly because they were now more well-off relatively speaking, and talking of clothes other than their normal work clothes, and their Sunday best, began to make sense).